# Couldn't Run the .py file | AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableSequence'

Tags: python, traceback, pyxb

I am working with odx files and I have a generate.py file to run. I am using pyXB. When I try to run I am getting this.

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rohitkr\Downloads\starter_kit_adas-master\starter_kit_adas-master\devops\scripts\generate_odxf\generate_odxf.py", line 15, in 
from schema import odx

File "C:\Users\rohitkr\Downloads\starter_kit_adas-master\starter_kit_adas-master\devops\scripts\generate_odxf\schema\odx.py", line 9, in                                                                                           import pyxb.binding

File "C:\Users\rohitkr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyxb\binding_*init*_.py", line 8, in 
from . import datatypes

File "C:\Users\rohitkr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyxb\binding\datatypes.py", line 1266, in 
rom . import content

File "C:\Users\rohitkr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyxb\binding\content.py", line 807, in 
class _PluralBinding (collections.MutableSequence):

AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableSequence'*
'''

What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In python 3.10 MutableSequence was removed from `collections` in favor of `collections.abc`

> Deprecated since version 3.3, will be removed in version 3.10: Moved Collections Abstract Base Classes to the collections.abc module. For backwards compatibility, they continue to be visible in this module through Python 3.9.

```py
>>> from collections import MutableSequence
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableSequence' from 'collections' (C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)

>>> from collections.abc import MutableSequence
```

Comment: I changed from collections to collections.abc and then it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to change the source code, there is an easier way. Just use this in your script after importing.

```
import collections
collections.MutableSequence = collections.abc.MutableSequence
```